# Multiple anonymous function MATLAB

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, derivative

My goal is to compute the **derivative** of a function and **use this result** as **another** function. Clearly, it means :

```
f = @(x) (x-1)*(x-2);      %A simple function
derivative = jacobian(f,x) %MATLAB output : "2*x - 3"
df = @(x) derivative       %= @(x) 2*x - 3
df(2)                      %= "2*x -3" instead of 2*2 - 3
```

How can I do such a thing ? I tried **syms x** but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`matlabFunction`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html):

> `g = matlabFunction(f)` converts the symbolic expression or function `f` to a MATLAB function with handle `g`.

In your example:

```
>> syms x
>> f = @(x) (x-1)*(x-2);
>> derivative = jacobian(f,x);
>> df = matlabFunction(derivative)
df =
  function_handle with value:
    @(x)x.*2.0-3.0
>> df(2)
ans =
     1
```